# list of ggplot with marrangeGrob, wrongly plot the same

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am struggling with marrangeGrob.  I need to plot many (many) histograms on multiple pages.  The logic of my code can be written with the iris dataset.

```
library(ggplot)
library(gridExtra)

num_columns=5
num_rows=5
num_pages=3

val=num_columns*num_rows*num_pages
vplots=list()

for(i in 1:val){
    aname=sample(colnames(iris)[1:4],1) # randomly pick a column name
    vals=sample(iris[,aname], 50, replace=TRUE) # with that column, pick 50 random values
    a_hist=ggplot(mapping=aes(vals)) + geom_histogram() + xlab(aname)  #plotting the histogram
    vplots[[i]]=a_hist # store the plot in the list
    fn=paste0("single_plot_",i,".png")
    ggsave(a_hist, filename =fn)
}


ggsave("arrange5x5.pdf", marrangeGrob(grobs=vplots, nrow=5, ncol=5), width = 15, height=15)
```

The problem I have is the following.  Each histogram is slightly different as it is possible to see from the "single_plot_N.png".  When I try to put all these plots in the same file, by using marrageGrob, all the histograms are the same.  What am I doing wrong?

Histogram 1:
[image]
Histogram 2:
[image]
Multiple plots on one file, all the histograms are the same (why?):
[image]

Comment: Define `data` inside `ggplot` using: `df <- data.frame(vals=vals)` and `a_hist <- ggplot(mapping=aes(vals), data=df)`

Comment: Yes, this comment solved the problem.  Please, put it as answer such that I can upvote it and give it the accept answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `data` object inside `ggplot`, i.e. the dataset to use for plot:

```
set.seed(1)
num_columns=2
num_rows=2
num_pages=1
val=num_columns*num_rows*num_pages
vplots=list()

for(i in 1:val) {
    aname=sample(colnames(iris)[1:4],1) # randomly pick a column name
    vals=sample(iris[,aname], 50, replace=TRUE) # with that column, pick 50 random values
    # Generate a data frame for ggplot
    df <- data.frame(vals=vals)
    # Input the dataset to use for plot
    a_hist=ggplot(mapping=aes(vals), data=df) + geom_histogram() + xlab(aname)  #plotting the histogram
    vplots[[i]]=a_hist 
}

grid.arrange(grobs=vplots, ncol=2)
```

[image]